# How to Environment setup in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to setup environments in my spring boot application like production or development. I have to use different  datasource  according to environment. So what is the right way to do it in spring boot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at profiles.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("production")
public class ProductionConfiguration {

    // ...

}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: I am also curious of the answer but is this related to `spring.main.web-environment= # detect by default` found here? http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html